# Writing ByteArray to file in c

Tags: c, pointers, arrays, fwrite

I have a struct which holds some ByteArray data

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t length;
    uint8_t* bytes;
} FREByteArray;
```

And here I am trying to save this to a file

```
FREByteArray byteArray;

if((fileToWrite = fopen(filePath, "wb+")) != NULL){
    fwrite(&byteArray.bytes, 1, byteArray.length, fileToWrite);
    fclose(fileToWrite);
}
```

But this doesn't seem to be saving all of the data, the saved file size is 16KB, actual data is about 32KB. I think fwrite is not able to write the whole bytearray to the file.

Is this the correct way to save the ByteArray? Is there a limit how much fwrite can handle in a single call?

Comment: Remove the `&`  in the `fwrite` line

Comment: `yteArray.bytes` is a pointer don't use `&` to get the address again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
fwrite(&byteArray.bytes, 1, byteArray.length, fileToWrite);
```

with

```
fwrite(byteArray.bytes, 1, byteArray.length, fileToWrite);
```

And as pointed out by @Sourav Ghosh  make sure that `byteArray.bytes` is pointing to the correct source location.

Comment: ..assuming `byteArray.bytes` is allocated memory properly. :-)

Comment: and assuming byteArray.length holds correct length.